# Websphere standalone EJB client keeps on prompting signer exchange prompt

Tags: ssl, ejb, client, websphere

I'm working on a Standalone EJB Client for Websphere and I'm trying to apply SSL on it. Whenever I run my client, the signer exchange prompt shows up and I accept. When I run it again, it still asks if I want to accept the signer certificate. I tried retrieving the signer certificates from port but it still prompts up. I created another client that is deployed on Websphere and used the both keystore and trustore of the standalone client and it worked. Is there a way to automatically accept the Signer certificate of the server?

Answer (score 0):

See the [Changing the signer auto-exchange prompt at the client](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/tsec_sslsignautoxchgclient.html) topic in the InfoCenter.

Comment: I think this instruction only works for administrative security